# Convert web document objects to a Spreadsheet function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using and spreadsheet, I have an HTML web that fills some text boxes and create some google charts when a csv file is dropped (this is not a Form)

[image]

I need to make a function that let me parse the value of the text boxes in order to fill a spreadsheet, this is my code so far:

Tablas.html (I am trying to pass all the document object as a parameter)

```
    <input id="cmd" onclick="formSubmit()" type="button" value="Descargar SnapShot">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function formSubmit() {
    google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(document);
    }
```

And the gs Script: (With the document as a parameter, i am trying to recover a text box named "modequ" to fill a new row in the Spreadsheet)

```
    function getValuesFromForm(document){
    var ssID   = "12GvIStMKqmRFNBM-C67NCDeb89-c55K7KQtcuEYmJWQ",
    sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0],
    modequ = document.getElementById("modequ").value;
    sheet.appendRow([modequ]);
    }
```

Is there any way to connect the all the document objects in the page made with the spreadsheet so i can append and process it? I though if maybe if i pass the all the document object this would be possible.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **document.getElementById()** method returns a reference from the id attribute from your HTML, it needs to be inside your **formSubmit()** function:

```
  function formSubmit() {
    var modequ = document.getElementById('modequ').value;
    google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(modequ);
  }
```

This way you can get all the values individually and then pass them as parameter e.g. `google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(modequ, tipmoto, smr)`

However, if you want to pass all the form elements and then get them by name, you can do something like this:

**HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
   <form id="form" name="form">
     <input name="modequ" type="text">
     <input name="tipmoto" type="text">
     <input name="series" type="text">
     <input id="cmd" onclick="formSubmit()" type="button" value="Descargar SnapShot">
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function formSubmit(){
   google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(document.forms[0]);
}
</script>
```

**GS:**

```
function getValuesFromForm(res){
  var ssID   = '12GvIStMKqmRFNBM-C67NCDeb89-c55K7KQtcuEYmJWQ',
      sheet  = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0];

  sheet.appendRow([res.modequ, res.tipmoto, res.series]);
}
```

Comment: That worked just fine, i see now i can´t escape from using forms as parameters to a Google Apps Script, i can live with that. Thanks